# pandas dataframe compare first and last row from each group

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe

How do I compare the value of the first row in col `b` and the last row in col `b` from grouping by col `a`, without using the `groupby` function? Because groupby function is very slow for a large dataset.

```
a = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3] 
b = [1,0,0,0,0,0,7,8,0,0,0,0,0,4,1,0,0,0,0,0,1]
```

Return two lists: one has the group names from col `a` where the last value is larger than the first value, etc.

```
larger_or_equal = [1,3]
smaller = [2]
```

Comment: I know I have an answer for this if I just understood the question.  Can you do a bit more work explaining what you are talking about?

Comment: Have you tried `groupby(sort=False)`? This can speed things up with a large dataset.

Comment: @piRSquared, groups `1` and `3` are selected because the last element in the group is greater than or equal to the first.

Comment: Bryan, I'd be curious to see performance comparisons between the three solutions, if you can share them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***All `numpy`***

```
a = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]) 
b = np.array([1,0,0,0,0,0,7,8,0,0,0,0,0,4,1,0,0,0,0,0,1])

w = np.where(a[1:] != a[:-1])[0]  # find the edges
e = np.append(w, len(a) - 1)  # define the end pos
s = np.append(0, w + 1)  # define start pos

# slice end pos with boolean array.  then slice groups with end postions.
# I could also have used start positions.
a[e[b[e] >= b[s]]]
a[e[b[e] < b[s]]]

[1 3]
[2]
```

Comment: Should be faster I guess!

Comment: I haven't tested it, but I'm assuming that's `True`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution without `groupby`. The idea is to shift column `a` to detect group changes:

```
df[df['a'].shift() != df['a']]

    a  b
0   1  1
7   2  8
14  3  1

df[df['a'].shift(-1) != df['a']]

    a  b
6   1  7
13  2  4
20  3  1
```

We will compare the column `b` in those two dataframes. We simply need to reset the index for the pandas comparison to work:

```
first = df[df['a'].shift() != df['a']].reset_index(drop=True)
last = df[df['a'].shift(-1) != df['a']].reset_index(drop=True)
first.loc[last['b'] >= first['b'], 'a'].values

array([1, 3])
```

Then do the same with `<` to get the other groups. Or do a set difference.

---

As I wrote in the comments, `groupby(sort=False)` might well be faster depending on your dataset.